# Generate an adjacency matrix from Delaunay Triangulation in R

Tags: r, graph, geo

I have a dataframe with a list of coordinates (lat, long) as below:

```
point lat long
1  51 31
2  52 31
3  52 30
4  56 28
5  57 29
6  53 32
7  54 35
8  52 32
9  48 30
10 49 27
```

I already managed to generate the Delaunay triangulation using the code below:

```
library(deldir)
vtess <- deldir(df$lat, df$long)
plot(vtess, wlines="triang", wpoints="none", number=FALSE, add=TRUE, lty=1)
```

What I would like to do now is to generate an adjacency matrix (10 by 10 matrix) having the following cell values:

1. If the two nodes are NOT linked by an edge in the Delaunay triangulation: Value of the cell = 0
2. If the two nodes are linked by an edge in the Delaunay triangulation: Value of the cell = Geographic distance between the two nodes (using distm() from 'geosphere' package with DistVincenty option)

Comment: How did you generate the triangulation? It would be better if we could start from where you are rather than have to figure that out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjacency matrix is essentially available in the the output of the Delaunay triangulation, it just needs a little reformatting. We avoid the `distm` function because we don't want to calculate the distance between all pairs of points, just adjacent pairs. It is more efficient to just call the distance function directly.

```
library(deldir)
library(geosphere)

del = deldir(dd$lat, dd$long)
del$delsgs$dist = with(del$delsgs, 
    distVincentySphere(p1 = cbind(y1, x1), p2 = cbind(y2, x2))
)
# we use y,x because the triangulation was lat,long but 
# distVincentySphere expects long,lat

# create empty adjacency matrix, fill in distances
adj = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(dd), ncol = nrow(dd))
adj[as.matrix(del$delsgs[c("ind1", "ind2")])] = del$delsgs$dist
round(adj)
#        [,1]  [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7] [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
#  [1,]      0     0 131124      0      0      0      0    0 341685      0
#  [2,] 111319     0  68535      0      0 130321      0    0      0      0
#  [3,]      0     0      0      0      0      0      0    0      0      0
#  [4,]      0     0 464058      0      0      0      0    0      0 782155
#  [5,]      0     0      0 127147      0      0      0    0      0      0
#  [6,]      0     0 175378 422215 484616      0      0    0      0      0
#  [7,]      0     0      0      0 504301 227684      0    0 753748      0
#  [8,] 131124 68535      0      0      0 111319 299883    0 467662      0
#  [9,]      0     0 445278      0      0      0      0    0      0      0
# [10,]      0     0 395715      0      0      0      0    0 247685      0
```

---

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(text = "point lat long
1  51 31
2  52 31
3  52 30
4  56 28
5  57 29
6  53 32
7  54 35
8  52 32
9  48 30
10 49 27", header = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

**To OP: Please note the comments; for future posts it is important to make your post and code self-contained. There is little point in asking a question based on a transformation (Delaunay triangulation) of your sample data, if you don't share that transformation code.**

---

That aside, here is a step-by-step example how to construct an adjacency matrix according to your specifications. For simplicity, I here assume that by *"distance between the two nodes"* you mean *Euclidean* distance.

1. Let's load the sample data

   ```
   df <- read.table(text = 
       "point lat long
   1  51 31
   2  52 31
   3  52 30
   4  56 28
   5  57 29
   6  53 32
   7  54 35
   8  52 32
   9  48 30
   10 49 27", header = T)
   ```
2. We first perform Delaunay triangulation using `deldir` from the `deldir` package.

   ```
   library(deldir)
   dxy <- deldir(df$lat, df$long)
   ```

   Let's plot the result

   ```
   plot(df$lat, df$long, col = "red")
   text(df$lat, df$long, df$point, cex = 0.5, col = "red", pos = 2)
   plot(dxy, wlines = "triang", wpoints = "none", add = T)
   ```

   [image]
3. Next, we extract the vertices from the Delaunay triangulation

   ```
   # Extract the Delaunay vertices
   vert <- data.frame(
       id1 = dxy$delsgs$ind1,
       id2 = dxy$delsgs$ind2)
   ```
4. We calculate Euclidean distances between all connected nodes, and reshape results in a `data.frame`

   ```
   # Construct adjacency matrix
   library(tidyverse)
   dist.eucl <- function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))
   df.adj <- vert %>%
       mutate_all(funs(factor(., levels = df$point))) %>%
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(val = dist.eucl(df[id1, 2:3], df[id2, 2:3])) %>%
       ungroup() %>%
       complete(id1, id2, fill = list(val = 0)) %>%
       spread(id1, val)
   ## A tibble: 10 x 11
   #   id2     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`
   #   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
   # 1 1      0.    1.00    0.  0.    0.    0.    0.    1.41    0.  0.
   # 2 2      0.    0.      0.  0.    0.    0.    0.    1.00    0.  0.
   # 3 3      1.41  1.00    0.  4.47  0.    2.24  0.    0.      4.  4.24
   # 4 4      0.    0.      0.  0.    1.41  5.00  0.    0.      0.  0.
   # 5 5      0.    0.      0.  0.    0.    5.00  6.71  0.      0.  0.
   # 6 6      0.    1.41    0.  0.    0.    0.    3.16  1.00    0.  0.
   # 7 7      0.    0.      0.  0.    0.    0.    0.    3.61    0.  0.
   # 8 8      0.    0.      0.  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.      0.  0.
   # 9 9      3.16  0.      0.  0.    0.    0.    7.81  4.47    0.  3.16
   #10 10     0.    0.      0.  7.07  0.    0.    0.    0.      0.  0.
   ```

   Note that you can replace `dist.eucl.` with any other distance metric, e.g. Haversine, cosine, etc. I chose `dist.eucl` only because of convenience.
5. The adjacency `matrix` is then simply

   ```
   df.adj %>% select(-id2) %>% as.matrix()
   #            1        2 3        4        5        6        7        8 9
   #[1,] 0.000000 1.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.414214 0
   #[2,] 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 0
   #[3,] 1.414214 1.000000 0 4.472136 0.000000 2.236068 0.000000 0.000000 4
   #[4,] 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 1.414214 5.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0
   #[5,] 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 5.000000 6.708204 0.000000 0
   #[6,] 0.000000 1.414214 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 3.162278 1.000000 0
   #[7,] 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 3.605551 0
   #[8,] 0.000000 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0
   #[9,] 3.162278 0.000000 0 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 7.810250 4.472136 0
   #[10,] 0.000000 0.000000 0 7.071068 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0
   #           10
   #[1,] 0.000000
   #[2,] 0.000000
   #[3,] 4.242641
   #[4,] 0.000000
   #[5,] 0.000000
   #[6,] 0.000000
   #[7,] 0.000000
   #[8,] 0.000000
   #[9,] 3.162278
   #[10,] 0.000000
   ```